# Subtracting 2 sub queries in SSRS as an expression

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I am trying to subtract 2 sub string to get a backlog of application and i am getting stuck. Can someone help me out here. The SSRS expression i am trying to write is below. What am i doing wrong?

The query will execute but won't subtract to 2 sub strings:

```
=SUM(IIf(Fields!NAME.Value = "TOTAL OUTSTANDING APPLICATIONS"
, Fields!DAYS_AGO.Value
, Nothing))  - SUM(IIf(Fields!NAME.Value = "ELECTION FORM RECEIVED"
, Fields!DAYS_AGO.Value
, Nothing))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are aggregating **NULL** values with your data which results in NULL.

As long as the rest of your logic is correct, it should work if you replace the **Nothing**s with 0.

```
=SUM(IIf(Fields!NAME.Value = "TOTAL OUTSTANDING APPLICATIONS"
, Fields!DAYS_AGO.Value
, 0))  - SUM(IIf(Fields!NAME.Value = "ELECTION FORM RECEIVED"
, Fields!DAYS_AGO.Value
, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That did not work, it displayed the same data. Is there another way to write this expression?

Comment: TOTAL OUTSTANDING APPLICATIONS (65) - ELECTION FORM RECEIVED(15) = 50. I always get 65 as the sum.

Comment: I found the issue. It is pulling in another sub string from a different report name. Your expression did work by adding the 0.